# Jersey: Detect when Controller Class is Created

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I've implemented a JAX-RS server application using Jersey 2.24.

I use the Guice-HK2 bridge so that the controller classes (those annotated with `@Path`) are injected with dependencies from Guice, not Jersey/HK2.

However, HK2 still creates instances of the `@Path` annotated classes itself.

Is there a way I can plug into Jersey/HK2 so that I'm notified when a `@Path` annotated class is created?  Like some sort of lifecycle listener?  Every time a `@Path` annotated class is created by Jersey/HK2 I want to do some registering/logging of that class.

If Guice were doing the actual creation of the `@Path` annotated class I think I could do it using a generic `Provider` but that's not available in this case, since Jersey/HK2 is creating the actual instance.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the least intrusive way would be to just use AOP. HK2 offers AOP. What you can do is create a `ConstructorInterceptor`. Something like

```
public class LoggingConstructorInterceptor implements ConstructorInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOG
            = Logger.getLogger(LoggingConstructorInterceptor.class.getName());

    @Override
    public Object construct(ConstructorInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        Constructor ctor = invocation.getConstructor();
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Creating: {0}", ctor.getDeclaringClass().getName());

        // returned instance from constructor invocation.
        Object instance = invocation.proceed();
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Created Instance: {0}", instance.toString());

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then create a `InterceptorService` to only use the interceptor for classes annotated with `@Path`

```
public class PathInterceptionService implements InterceptionService {

    private static final ConstructorInterceptor CTOR_INTERCEPTOR
            = new LoggingConstructorInterceptor();
    private final static List<ConstructorInterceptor> CTOR_LIST
            = Collections.singletonList(CTOR_INTERCEPTOR);

    @Override
    public Filter getDescriptorFilter() {
        return BuilderHelper.allFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public List<MethodInterceptor> getMethodInterceptors(Method method) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ConstructorInterceptor> getConstructorInterceptors(Constructor<?> ctor) {
        if (ctor.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) {
            return CTOR_LIST;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then just register the `InterceptionService` and `ConstructorInterceptor` with the DI system

```
new ResourceConfig()
        .register(new AbstractBinder(){
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                bind(PathInterceptionService.class)
                        .to(InterceptionService.class)
                        .in(Singleton.class);
                    bind(LoggingConstructorInterceptor.class)
                        .to(ConstructorInterceptor.class)
                        .in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
```

See complete example in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/ef54c2dccba390eb906b2d4a29ea3920)

**See Also:**

- [HK2 documentation on AOP](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/extensibility.html#Interception)

Comment: That worked!!  Thank you very much!!  I did notice that the binding of line 91 isn't necessary, because the class is just created with the `new` keyword and isn't injected.

Comment: Yeah your right. I think I was experimenting with a bunch of different things.